# Nulling a string or any type when don't know return value?

Tags: c#, servicemanager

What is the best way to null a item if you don't know what its value can be? I am going through objects which can be of any type from an object. How can I cast when I don't know what the return value might be?

```
string viewValue
    = emop.Object[null, viewDetails.Columns[i].Property] != null
          ? emop.Object[null, viewDetails.Columns[i].Property].Value.ToString()
          : string.Empty;
```

I thought it might be better to cast all the objects as string but some items it's failing on saying item is null.

Comment: It's not clear why you need to convert them to string, pumping memory with double data. what is a reason behind that ?

Comment: Oh I **guess** you may also check if `Value `is not `null` (not only `emop.Object[null, viewDetails.Columns[i].Property]`). Don't do that in one line, it's confusing enough...

Comment: Your code is failing because you are checking if the item is not null, but then *not* checking if the .Value is not null before calling .ToString() on it.

Comment: @JoelC can you add example please JoelC with example so I can mark you up thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without approving of your conversion to a string for all objects, since I don't know the data you're working on. I believe this would fix your actual error.

```
string viewValue
= emop.Object[null, viewDetails.Columns[i].Property] != null && emop.Object[null, viewDetails.Columns[i].Property].Value != null
      ? emop.Object[null, viewDetails.Columns[i].Property].Value.ToString()
      : string.Empty;
```

I added a not null check against the .Value property. Otherwise calling .ToString() could be calling against a null object.